# Nuka-carousel react move to certain slide

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, carousel

I've got a question about npm package 'nuka-carousel. How to perform goToSlide on clicked element. I have list of elements with scroll3d setting. If I click on e.g last visible element I would like to scroll carousel so that element would be in a center.

Answer (score 0):

According to their [GitHub documentation](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/nuka-carousel#external-control-of-carousel-state), you can take control of the carousel just by adding `onClick` to your control button and then use `setState()` to change the `slideIndex`:

```
import React from 'react';
import Carousel from 'nuka-carousel';

export default class extends React.Component {
  state = {
    slideIndex: 0
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Carousel
        slideIndex={this.state.slideIndex}
        afterSlide={slideIndex => this.setState({ slideIndex })}
      >
      ...
      </Carousel>
      <button onClick={(event) => this.handlesClick(event, index)}> />
    );
  }

  handleClick = (event, index) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({slideIndex: index});
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank You but since mixins are deprecated so do You have any info how I could use it either latest React version?

Comment: you're right, if you're using es6 there's a better way to take control of the carousel. I'll update my answer with this new code!